# What was the first Hebrew date of the first Molad?

Tags: calendar, creation, astronomy, moon, kiddush-hachodesh

If one were to represent the Molad Tohu as a date, comprised of a month, day, year, hours, minutes, seconds, and chalakim, what date would that be?

Comment: The world was created on the 25th of Elul, and there was no Jerusalem (dry land was created later)

Comment: There was a first Molad though, right? What does no Jerusalem have to do with anything in this context? At some point there was, and then there was a molad.

Comment: See [Rambam Kiddush Hachodesh 6 8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3806.htm#8)

Comment: @ba Why would Jerusalem matter anyway?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not that there wouldn't be a molad, but that any place in the world would work (if I remember correctly, the molad we say is on Jerusalem, but I'm not familiar with the topic)

Answer (score 2):

The רמב"ם in הלכות קידוש החודש פרק ו says in [הלכה ח](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3806.htm):

> והמולד הראשון שממנו תתחיל, הוא מולד שהיה בשנה ראשונה של יצירה, והוא
>   היה בליל שני חמש שעות בלילה ומאתיים וארבעה חלקים, סימן להם ב' ה' ר"ד;
>   וממנו היא התחלת החשבון.

So Molad Tohu was on Sunday night, 2 Tishrie year 0001, 5 hours and 204 parts after sunset, i.e. 23:11 PM and  33⅓ seconds, according to [Hebrew Calendar Science and Myths](http://hebrewcalendar.tripod.com/#06) - or Monday 7 September 1748 BCE at 11:11:33.33' PM.

Comment: -1. That's not exactly true. 2-5-204 is the molad of Shnas Tohu - the make-believe year that contained five days of Creation. So it's the molad of Tishrei of year 0. The molad of year 1, as recorded further in that Rambam, is 6-14-0, Friday at exactly 14 hours and no chalakim.